# table with subtables, sum of width more than \linewidth

Tags: tables

Code sth like this:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{...}
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
...
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
...
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

I have to make it slightly larger in width so that the contained tabular fits in.

Multiple issues:

- The result is not centered as I want it.
- It only increases in width to the right. (Which is basically the same problem reformulated.)
- On the subtable, I get a warning `overfull \hbox`.

How do I resolve this?

I was thinking about increasing the `\linewidth` within the `table`, but I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: You can use the `adjustwidth` environment, from `changepage`, to increase `\linewidth`both on the left and n the right margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `\makebox[\textwidth]` command:

(The tikzpicture added to show the real 1.1\textwidth)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test Table caption}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\begin{subtable}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
Test Text here e& long enough to fill &  line \\
Test Text here e& long enough to fill &  line \\
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Test Text here & long enough to fill &  line\\
Test Text here & long enough to fill &  line \\
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}}
\end{table}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-,red](0,0)--(1.1\textwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]